# SQLWatch - notifications not being sent

Tags: sql-server

I’m wondering if someone with knowledge/experience of SQLWatch could help me out with something.
We have SQLWatch set up on 2 DEV servers and 1 Central monitoring server, its working fine and the data from the 2 DEV servers is coming over to the central server, I can see alerts are being recorded in the table - [dbo].[sqlwatch_logger_check].

However, our issue that we are not being notified by any means (email, Powershell script running).
What’s interesting is that if we drop a row into the table [dbo].[sqlwatch_meta_action_queue] then alert notification does happen.

So our issue seems to be for some reason alerts are being raised but the record is not being inserted into the queue table. I suspect some sort of mapping issue but as it stands now it all looks ok, I use the following to check

```
    SELECT C.check_id,check_name,check_description,check_enabled,A.action_description,A.action_exec_type,A.action_exec
FROM [dbo].[sqlwatch_config_check] C
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[sqlwatch_config_check_action] CA ON C.check_id = CA.check_id
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[sqlwatch_config_action] A ON CA.action_id = A.action_id
WHERe C.check_id = -1
```

And it shows the failed job is set to run our PowerShell script, which it does when the row is manually inserted.
Any ideas on what the cause may be here?
Thanks,
Nic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the creator of SQLWATCH.

Firstly, just to clarify, default notifications that come with SQLWATCH only work in a local scope i.e. they will happen on each monitored instance where `@@SERVERNAME = sql_instance`. If you are expecting the default notifications to fire from the central server for a remote instance this will not happen. The default notifications on the central server will only fire for the central server itself and not for data imported from the remote instances. This is done to avoid a situation where pull into the central repository is rare and thus notifications could be well delayed.

However, there is nothing stopping you from creating Check Rules or Reports to fire on the back of the imported data.

Secondly, the checks are not alerts per se. Checks are just... well, checks... that run periodically and make sure everything is in order. Checks can trigger an action to send an email. For this, as you have worked out, there is an association table that links together checks and actions.

As for your problem, is the actual action enabled? All actions that are not associated with report are disabled by default as they need to be configured first:

[image]
Add a column to your query to bring `action_enabled` column:

```
SELECT C.check_id, check_name, check_description, check_enabled, A.action_description, A.action_exec_type, A.action_exec, [action_enabled]
FROM [dbo].[sqlwatch_config_check] C
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[sqlwatch_config_check_action] CA ON C.check_id = CA.check_id
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[sqlwatch_config_action] A ON CA.action_id = A.action_id
WHERE C.check_id = -1
```

Or, there is already a view that should provide you with the complete mapping:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[vw_sqlwatch_report_config_check_action]
  WHERE check_id = -1
```

The application log table `[dbo].[sqlwatch_app_log]` should also contain valuable information. Did you look in there for anything out of ordinary?

## Summarising

In order to enable alerts in a brand new install of SQLWATCH, all it's needed is setting up `action_exec` with your email details and `action_enabled` set to 1. If you have made some other changes it may be easier to reinstall back to default.

Comment: Hi Marcin, firstly thanks for the reply and for building such an impressive solution, I'll review the above and let you know how we get on. Thanks again for making my life so much easier.